# What is the Difference between * and column_name in MySQL SELECT query

Tags: mysql, select

Here is an exemple:

Table1
-columnA
-columnB

Question:

What is the difference between

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
```

and

```
SELECT columnA, columnB FROM Table1
```

I know those two query return the same result. But is there a difference or do those two queries do the exact same thing?

And furthermore, how does MySQL server process those?

Could someone point any documentation on this please?

Thank you!

Sebastien

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference. It's a matter of projection of columns.

When you use `*`, you have no control over the column names. It just selects all columns in your table.

While specifying the column names can be more flexible, *in my own opinion*, because you can give column names an `alias` and you can perform some actions in the column such as passing it into the function.

Comment: Also, `select *`  will behave differently from `SELECT columnA, columnB` when someone adds columnC to the table in the future.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful and answered pretty much all my questions! And thank you to @AlessandroFalivene for the doc!

Answer (score 0):

select * from table1

returns all the columns in Table1.

Reference manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index.html (MySql 5.1)

Answer (score 0):

This are the differences:

```
select count(*) from table, count all registers on that table,
```

Very similar to

```
select count(1) from table, count all registers on that table
```

And

```
select count(column_name) from table,
```

Count all registers on that table where column_name is not null

Answer (score 0):

If you select the columns specifically, and later change the structure of the table by adding, removing, or renaming a column, you will be forced to edit your queries to make them work (or, in the case of adding a column, to include the additional data). Selecting `*` will load all the columns regardless of what those columns are, so if the table structure is later updated your queries will still fully work.

HOWEVER: if your query is meant to include a join, you will need to prefix the `*` with the table name, and there is the risk of column name collision if both tables have columns with the same name. So in the case of joined queries, I think it's always a good idea to select individual columns from each table, rather than `*` from one table and individual columns from the other.

Selecting individual columns also allows you to rename the columns with aliases, as such:

```
SELECT column_1 AS first, column_2 AS second
FROM some_table
```

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, avoid "SELECT *". It's evil, slow and makes your code harder to read when you return to it months later. Instead, name and qualify your columns. Alias your table instances (and your columns too if you like)...

```
SELECT x.something, y.something_else FROM my_table x JOIN my_other_table y ON y.id = x.id
```

If you look at many of my other responses on SO, you'll see that I don't always heed this advice, but it IS good advice nonetheless!